# Trigger code or date format error in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using a capturing software, Abbyy FlexiCapture, after user done the verification (some sort of user key in data). It will export captured data into SQL Server 2008 R2

Once SQL Server identify there is an **inserted data** (new row), it will **trigger** code to **update** table Abbyy base on business rule.

The table has two columns called `ProcessingDate` and `DateOfService`

My business rule requirement is

1. If Processing Date is later than Date Of Service 7 month, it will update Table Abbyy

   - column `CouponStatus` with "**Reject**",
   - column `RejectCode` with "**A5**".
2. If Processing Date is earlier than Date Of ServiceDate 7 month, it will update Table Abbyy

   - column `CouponStatus` with "Approve",
   - column `RejectCode` with "null".

I am facing an error because some inserted data with Processing Date **more than** Service Date 7 month, column `CouponStatus` become "**Approve**".

I am not sure is my trigger code problem or date format problem.
when user do validation, the date format is `dd/mm/yy`,

In SQL Server 2008 R2, my `ProcessingDate` and `DateOfService` column's datatype is `date` with format `yyyy-mm-dd`

Here are my trigger code, pls focus start on line 86

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[BusinessRule]    Script Date: 10/03/2012 11:28:05 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author: <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[BusinessRule]
ON [dbo].[Abbyy]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;


DECLARE @Identity varchar(225);
DECLARE @RegNo varchar(225);
DECLARE @ProDate date;
DECLARE @SerDate date;
DECLARE @PriKey varchar(255);

SELECT @Identity=EngineNo, @RegNo=VehRegNo, @ProDate=ProcessingDate, @SerDate=DateOfService,@PriKey=DocID FROM Inserted

--If EngineNo not exist in db, update Reject & A1
IF EXISTS (Select EngineNo
            From Abbyy
            Where
                NOT EXISTS
                (Select EngineNo
                 From eDaftarOwnerDetail
                 where eDaftarOwnerDetail.EngineNo = @Identity))

    UPDATE Abbyy
    SET CouponStatus = 'Reject', RejectCode = 'A1'
    WHERE EngineNo = @Identity
    and DocID=@PriKey

--If Vehicle Registration No not exist in db, update Reject & A2
Else If EXISTS (Select VehRegNo
                From Abbyy
                Where
                    NOT EXISTS
                    (Select VehRegNo
                     From eDaftarOwnerDetail
                     Where eDaftarOwnerDetail.VehRegNo = @RegNo))
    UPDATE Abbyy
    SET CouponStatus = 'Reject', RejectCode = 'A2'
    WHERE VehRegNo = @RegNo
    and DocID=@PriKey

--If EngineNo & Vehicle Registration No does not matched, update Reject & A3
Else If EXISTS (Select EngineNo, VehRegNo
                From Abbyy
                Where
                    NOT EXISTS
                    (Select EngineNo, VehRegNo
                     From eDaftarOwnerDetail
                     Where eDaftarOwnerDetail.EngineNo = @Identity
                     and eDaftarOwnerDetail.VehRegNo = @RegNo))
    UPDATE Abbyy
    SET CouponStatus = 'Reject', RejectCode = 'A3'
    WHERE EngineNo = @Identity
    and VehRegNo = @RegNo
    and DocID=@PriKey

-- If EngineNo exist in db more then twice, update Reject & A4
Else If EXISTS (Select COUNT(1)
                From Abbyy
                Where EngineNo = @Identity
                Group by EngineNo 
                Having COUNT(1)>2)
    UPDATE Abbyy
    SET CouponStatus = 'Reject', RejectCode = 'A4'
    WHERE EngineNo = @Identity
    and DocID=@PriKey

-- If ProcessingDate more than ServiceDate 210 days, update Reject & A5 
Else If EXISTS (Select ProcessingDate, DateOfService
                From Abbyy
                Where
                datediff(day, @SerDate, @ProDate)>210)
    UPDATE Abbyy
    SET CouponStatus = 'Reject', RejectCode = 'A5'
    WHERE ProcessingDate = @ProDate
    and DateOfService = @SerDate
    and DocID=@PriKey

Else
UPDATE Abbyy
Set CouponStatus = 'Approve', RejectCode = ''
WHERE EngineNo = @Identity

-- Insert statements for trigger here

END
```

Appreciate anyone can give me some guideline to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: `DATE` in SQL Server **does not have ANY format** associated with it - it's just a numerical value being stored.

Comment: Your trigger is broken. `inserted` can contain multiple rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do some kind of date formatting before comparison to convert both values to the same format

Example :

```
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR,ProcessingDate,102) = CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ProDate,102)
```

OR

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,ProcessingDate,102) = CONVERT(DATE,@ProDate,102)
```

Comment: Converting dates to strings (your first example) and then working with them (e.g. comparisons) is usually the first step to new and interesting bugs. Keep dates as dates, and convert strings that should be dates into dates first (closer to your second example)

Comment: Dear Damie_The_Unbeliever:
What you mean by trigger is broken. My inserted data (new row) is not single row but is from 50 to 1000 row records.
I don't understand (your first example) & (closer to you second example) refer to which part?

Comment: Dear Prasanna:  Mind to ask is this date formatting add into trigger? If yes, after which line? Thanks.

Comment: Whenever you compare dates, convert to a common format first, as shown here

Comment: Dear Prasanna
I change to

SELECT @Identity=EngineNo, @RegNo=VehRegNo, @ProDate=ProcessingDate, @SerDate=DateOfService,@PriKey=DocID FROM Inserted
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,ProcessingDate,102) = CONVERT(DATE,@ProDate,102) AND
CONVERT(DATE,DateOfService,102) = CONVERT(DATE,@SerDate,102)

but It's not work, pls advice.

Comment: You have selected as ProDate=ProcessingDate. And compared those in WHERE clause. ProDate should have some value before comparing! Seems here ProDate does not have a value when comparing

Comment: In question (original) you did not included a WHERE clause in SELECT @Identity=EngineNo, @RegNo=VehRegNo, @ProDate=ProcessingDate, @SerDate=DateOfService,@PriKey=DocID FROM Inserted
--> Why now its there?

Comment: Dear Prasanna
so I should code like this (1) 
SELECT @Identity=EngineNo, @RegNo=VehRegNo, @ProDate=ProcessingDate, @SerDate=DateOfService, @PriKey=DocID FROM Inserted

Comment: Dear Prasanna so I should code like this (2)
Else If EXISTS (Select ProcessingDate, DateOfService
    From Abbyy
    Where
    datediff(day, @SerDate, @ProDate)>210)
 UPDATE Abbyy
 SET CouponStatus = 'Reject', RejectCode = 'A5'
 WHERE CONVERT(DATE,ProcessingDate,102) = CONVERT(DATE,@ProDate,102)
 and CONVERT(DATE,DateOfService,102) = CONVERT(DATE,@SerDate,102)
 and DocID=@PriKey